How can I loop through interactive grid and calculate low and high limit or for each row?
I have interactive grid and I need to calculate low limit and high limit depends on values
of mean and SD and this is the equation
low = (mean - sd) * 2 
high = (mean + sd) * 2  

this is the example see image :

I need when click the button calculate low limit and high limit execute the calculations
I have old C sharp program and I did the loop and calculation when button pressed and this is the C sharp code :
  private void btnsdi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dgvResult.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString()) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString()))
                {
                   
                    string mean = dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                    string sd = dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();

                    dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value = (Convert.ToDecimal(mean) - (Convert.ToDecimal(sd) * 2));
                    dgvResult.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = (+Convert.ToDecimal(mean) +(Convert.ToDecimal(sd) * 2));
                  
                }

            }
        }

How can I loop and do the calculation when click the button in interactive grid or if I can do it for each row when enter mean and SD do calculation by the row ?

Without having tested, this is what I would do:
Create a dynamic action on change of mean, sd that calculates the low and another one that calculates the high. Set action to fire on page load. This will ensure that the value is always up to date (on page load and on change) and there is no button needed.

I solved it by using dynamic action as the following steps :
1- Add STATIC ID for columns MEAN , SD , LOW and HIGH
2- create dynamic action on change MEAN and SD
3- the true action will be Execute JavaScript code and this is the code :
var mean = ($v("T_MEAN") != "")?parseFloat($v("T_MEAN")):0;
var sd = ($v("T_SD") != "")?parseFloat($v("T_SD")):0;
var low = 0;
var high = 0;

if(!isNaN(mean) && !isNaN(sd)) 
{
    low = mean - (sd * 2);
    high = mean + (sd *2);
}
$s("T_LOW",low);
$s("T_HIGH",high);

4- this code will work and calculate for each row direct when type mean and SD value will calculate low and high column value.
